# Reading SAS files on a remote server

Tags: python, paramiko

I need to read some files on a remote server via Python. I can use paramiko to login into this remote server and get a file object (variable remote_file below). The issue is that this is a SAS file and so the encoding doesn't allow me to read one line at a time. I need to use SAS7BDAT package to read this file. However, sas7bdat package accepts only file path or buffer as input. Is it possible to convert the file object (remote_file) so that sas7bdat can accept it? Appreciate any help here!

I know there are some workarounds that can solve this (install Python on remote server, move file on remote server to local machine). However, I'm not looking for these solutions. I have SAS installed on my local machine and I have full write access to the remote machine. If I can transfer the SAS7BDAT file to CSV on the remote desktop and then read the CSV file, that works for me too. (all of this should be done via Python though)

**Using paramiko package**

```
import paramiko
from contextlib import contextmanager
ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy()) 
ssh_client.connect('host name', username='username', password='password')

sftp_client = ssh_client.open_sftp()
remote_file = sftp_client.open('file path','r')
for line in remote_file: # fails here
    print line # fails here
```

**Using SAS7BDAT package**

```
import sas7bdat
from sas7bdat import SAS7BDAT
f = SAS7BDAT('file_path_or_buffer')
```

Comment: Is it better to download the file locally using paramiko and use SAS7BDAT?

Comment: I don't want to download the file locally. These can be massive and so this method will take too long.

Comment: What is the difference? Even if you open the file remotely, it has to transfer the file locally as your process is local.

Comment: Your response helped me debug this actually. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
import paramiko
import pandas as pd

host = "your_host.com"
port = your_port

transport = paramiko.Transport((host, port))
transport.connect(username = user_id, password = password)
sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)

with sftp.open(path_to_file, "r") as file:
    df = pd.read_sas(file, format ='sas7bdat',  encoding = 'latin1')
```

You may need to adjust the encoding, but latin1 is the SAS standard.